# How to filter the lines of a pandas.Dataframe based on Boolean values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I need a smart and fast algorithm to delete all the rows of a Pandas dataframe [10000:37] for which I observe Boolean value False at least in one of the columns (for each row) of a twin dictionary to the dataframe (I mean that the dictionary has keys equal to the name of the columns of the dataframe while the values of each keys are lists of length 9999 of Boolean values).

I would like to apply this operation easily even in view of future implementations and program modifications, thus avoiding separate operations on the different series of values.
I state that I am not a professional programmer. can anyone recommend an appropriate route?

Comment: Could you provide some code to illustrate ?

Answer (score 0):

Using this as an example dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': [True,True,True], 'B': [False,True,True], 'C' : [True,False,True], 'D' : [True,True,True]})
```

We only want the 3rd row which has `True` in each column:

```
mask = test_df.all(axis=1)
keep_df = test_df[mask]
```

If you only want to check columns that are keys in your dictionary:

```
d = { 'A': [1,2,3], 'C': [4,5,6] }
mask = test_df[d].all(axis=1)
keep_df = test_df[mask]
```

Comment: my dataframe and my dict have the same dimensions and names of the columns == keys of the dict. But my dataframe's elements are numbers and the dict's elements are the boolenas values that i would like to use to drop rows from the dataframe.

Comment: If the column names are always equal to the dictionary keys then either of my methods will work. If there is ever any difference and you only want to check the dictionary keys then use the second method.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume here that the dictionary and the dataframe have different values but share same indices. Said differently, I assume that the index of the dataframe is a `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=10000, step=1)`.

In that case, I would build a dataframe from the twin dictionary, and use `np.all`  to identify the rows having at least a False in any column.

Let us call `df` the dataframe and `twin` the twin dictionary, code could be:

```
df_twin = pd.DataFrame(twin)
df_twin['to_drop'] = np.all(df_twin, axis=1)

df_clean = df.drop(df_twin.loc[~df_twin.to_drop].index)
```

Comment: I did a quick benchmark and I think python's builtin `all` is much faster than `np.all`.

Comment: @TBurgis: You are right. But my solution is vectorized, so despite `np.all` being less efficient that `all`, avoiding `apply` still leaves a gain ratio of 6 for a dataframe of size 1000.

Comment: Of course, you;'re right. I'm going to rewrite my answer to remove `apply`.